# Github api Login - get user

Tags: api, github, oauth

I have a problem with Github api.
I parse the access_token but when i try to get the user I get the following error:

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/user?access_token=mplamplampla): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

When I try to get the contents through address bar in my browser is working!

My code:

```
//Get the access token
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'client_id' => 'mplamplaID',
        'client_secret' => 'mplamplaSECRET',
        'code' => trim($_GET['code']),
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://vlingos.com/github.php'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$vip = file_get_contents('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',false,$context);
parse_str($vip);
//Get the User
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.github.com/user?access_token='.$access_token);
if(isset($json) and (is_array($json)===true or is_object($json)===true)){
    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
            foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
                $git_user[$key] = $val;
            }
print_r($git_user);
}else{
    echo "can't get user";
}
```

Can someone propose something?
kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Enable your token is correct. generate new token, refer to:https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

test it:
curl https://api.github.com/user?access_token=your token